# why I am getting error trying to add Foreign key to table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Not able to add foreign key to tbl1 referencing tbl2 (Desc), here are the two tables :
***please notice Tbl1 includes all values,tbl2 Has more values that doesn't necessarily exists in tbl1***

> Error(Msg 1776): There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'tbl2' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_desc'.

tbl1:

```
alter table tbl1 add constraint pk_desc primary key (desc)
The Error:**alter table tbl1 add constraint fk_desc foreign key (desc) 
references tbl2(desc)**
```

| Desc |
| --- |
| Astrogator |
| Geologist |
| Technician |

tbl2:

```
alter table tbl2 add constraint pk_canid_desc primary 
key(id,desc)
```

| ID | Desc |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | Astrogator |
| 1001 | Geologist |
| 1001 | Technician |
| 2003 | Biochemist |
|  |  |

thank you for the help,

Comment: What does "having trouble" mean? What exact syntax are you using and what exact error message are you getting?

Comment: And please post your error.

Comment: I do not get any error when I create the foreign key, see [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=479879c79a34b96c014ae038ab32f75f)

Comment: @GuidoG, the same didn't work for me , maybe because I am having primary key on both (id,Desc) columns ? Error: There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'tbl2' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'fk_descp'.

Comment: Aha, I did not notice you had both columns in your PK. Well, that means that column Desc in tbl2 is not unique, therefore it is not possible to link to it

Answer (score 0):

you cant make `Desc` that at table `tbl2` as a FK while it contains values not exists at the table `tbl1`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a foreign key is different depending on the flavor of SQL your using. For sql server you would bring up the parent db in SSMS using table design. Select Foreign key relationships and add a new relationship. From there select other table and column which has foreign key. Keep in mind that there needs to exist a foreign key for each Primary record or you will get an error.